# Unable to write error_log output... but only from a certain function

Tags: customization, themes, debug

The `replace_uploaded_image()` function works great! I know it works because when I login to WP Admin and upload an image, it does exactly what it is supposed to do. Furthermore, if I remove the function and go upload an image, the original uploaded image is there. (exactly what you would expect.)

I'm trying to see the contents of the variables within the function. I'm stumped about why it seems to execute all the code ***except*** the `write_log()` parts.

The custom_gallery function works and I have no problems there. I only included it to illustrate the fact that using `write_log()` within that function works fine.

The ***only*** time `write_log()` doesn't work is when called from within `replace_uploaded_image()`.

Any clue why it is like that?

```
<?php

/**
 * Replace default gallery HTML with my own.
 */
function custom_gallery ( $output, $attr ) {
    // Do some stuff
    // A bunch of code that works good.
    write_log ( 'test' );  // Writing string from here works.
    write_log( $object );  // writing array or object from here works.

    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'custom_gallery', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Delete the original uploaded image and use the large format in its place.
 */
function replace_uploaded_image ( $image_data ) {
    write_log ( 'test' );  // Nothing appears in error_log
    write_log ( $image_data );  // Nothing appears in error_log

    // if there is no large image : return
    if ( !isset ( $image_data['sizes']['large'] ) ) return $image_data;

    // paths to the uploaded image and the large image
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $image_data['file'];
    $current_subdir = substr( $image_data['file'], 0, strrpos($image_data['file'], '/' ) );
    $large_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $current_subdir . '/' . $image_data['sizes']['large']['file'];

    // delete the uploaded image
    unlink( $uploaded_image_location );

    // rename the large image
    rename( $large_image_location, $uploaded_image_location );

    // update image metadata and return them
    $image_data['width'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['width'];
    $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['height'];
    unset( $image_data['sizes']['large'] );

    write_log ( 'test' );  // Nothing appears in error_log
    write_log ( $image_data );  // Nothing appears in error_log

    return $image_data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'replace_uploaded_image' );

// for debugging. write to error log.
if ( !function_exists( 'write_log' ) ) {
    function write_log ( $log ) {
        if ( true === WP_DEBUG ) {
            error_log( '******************************' );
            if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
                error_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
            } else {
                error_log( $log );
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was looking in the wrong error_log file. Doh!

For anyone else who has this problem, remember to also check the error_log located in the wp_admin folder. Not just the one in WordPress root.